# Download a file from asset folder when clicking on a button

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-http

I am working on an angular2 project, I have a file in assets folder and I have created a button to download the file while running the app.

I see there are quite a many solutions to the above problem so i got confused. Can you please help.

```xml
<button pButton type="button" (click)="f1()" label="Download Sample Defaults 
XML File"></button>
```

I need code for f1() which can help me download the file to my Download folder when clicking on above button. Help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what does f1 do?

Comment: nothing yet, its jst to fill the space. Wouldnt metter if i remove it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can either style an anchor element to look like a button and set it's href to assets/file

```xml
<a href="assets/file">Download here</a>
```

Or create an anchor element on the fly, set it's href element and click it.

Something like:

```typescript
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
link.href = 'assets/file';
link.download = path;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.remove();
```

Comment: UI side is fine, i need help in actual function to get file. I am taking help from http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2017/12/download-file-in-angular-js2-application.html but its not helping

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense then

Comment: yeah i modified now. Thank you

Comment: Great edit...... So i did understood your question and i did provide you the answer.

Comment: ```link.download``` contains the desired name of the file to be downloaded. So, it can be modified as ```link.download: 'My File.csv'``` if you want the downloaded file to be called as "My File.csv"

Answer (score 17):

You don't need to change the template. Use this way

```typescript
f1() {
    window.open('path', '_blank');
}
```

ex:

```typescript
f1() {
   window.open('/assets/images/blabla.png', '_blank');
}
```

**update**

If you need to download file instead of opening a new tab use a link with html5 **download** attribute
ex:

```xml
<a download="filename" target="_blank" href="/assets/images/blabla.png">
  Click here to download image
</a>
```

Comment: yeah it opens file in another tab, but i need the function to download the file so i can see it in my downloads folder. thanks

Comment: ```window.open``` creates a popup which gets blocked by the browser most of the times.

Answer (score 12):

you can try this solution

> ts file code

```typescript
downloadFile(){
        let link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = "filename";
        link.href = "assets/images/user-image.png";
        link.click();
}
```

> html file code

```xml
<button (click)="downloadFile()">Download</button>
```

Comment: yeah you gave the exact answer but i had already figured it out from @Carsten answer. So

Comment: Hey can we try with the httpclient ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one.
Put the file in assets and give the path in href.

```html
<a class="iconsBG" title="Excel" href='/assets/Project-2021-05-17T10_41_22.378Z.xlsx' download="Project-2021-05-17T10_41_22.378Z.xlsx"><i class="far fa-file-excel"></i></a>
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work, short sweet and simple, the "download" and "#"-"yoclickme" makes it work

```xml
<a href="{{ this.fileurl }}" download #yoclickme></a> 
    <button (click)="yoclickme.click()"> Download </button>
```