# angular 4 / res.download from nodejs back-end

Tags: node.js, angular, api

I'm calling an Angular component which calls an api service I created to call a nodejs back-end. The back-end download a zip file, using res.download. I believe that the response is not correctly handled, because when I call the back-end directly from the url (localhost:3000/api/download/file), it works perfectly. Here's the code below :

1) Angular component

```
downloadZipFile(index) {
    this._apiService.downloadZip(index).subscribe(data => {
    });
  }
```

2) Angular apiService

```
downloadZip(index) {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000' + appConfig.__apiUrl + 'download/' + index);
  }
```

3) NodeJS API

```
router.get('/download/:index', (req, res) => {
  res.download(path.join(__dirname, 'downloads/' + req.params.index + '.zip'));
});
```

Comment: Resolved : Tried this solution and it works perfectly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907542/download-a-file-from-asset-folder-when-clicking-on-a-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attaching multiple time API url in your angular service HTTP request. Please remove one of them. and check again.

```
downloadZip(index) {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/download/' + index);
  }
```

Add above code in your service.

Comment: Thanks @shubham for your answer. It is normal, appConfil.__apiUrl is equal to a const '/api/', the issue is not coming from this part of the code. I believe  it is from the response handling.

Comment: It is not, the appConfig.__apiUrl is necessary in that case.

Comment: How is it possible to run directly without adding /api in the URL? you are saying this "localhost:3000/download/file" is working.

Comment: It was my mistake. I changed it to 'localhost:3000/api/download/file'. Sorry for that.

Comment: No, I still have the same issue. The code is running perfectly when I call directly 'localhost:3000/api/download/file', but does not work when the api is called from the front-end Angular.

Comment: For doing this thing you have two options.

1. Direct give file path in html file tag
2. Store file in angular project then download

Comment: I am storing the file in the Angular project. The code above is made to download that file.

Comment: Please check this link, i hope you will get your solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51789871/download-file-from-http-post-request-angular-6/51843771